# convert md5 checksum from Powershell to Shell Script

Tags: shell, powershell

I have a working script in Powershell:

```
function md5($text){
  $md5 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
  $md5.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::utf8.getbytes($text))|%{$HC=''}{$HC+=$_.tostring("x2")}{$HC}
}

$Password="D e o t 2 3 3 S w i t c h"
$Challenge="6 1 7 e 3 d 3 f"
$Code1=$Challenge+"-"+$Password 
echo $Code1
# gives "617e3d3f-Deot233Switch"
$Code2=[char[]]$Code1|%{$Code2=""}{$Code2+=$_+[Char]0}{$Code2}
echo $Code2
# gives "6 1 7 e 3 d 3 f - D e o t 2 3 3 S w i t c h"
# I dont know how to do that in Shell
$Response= $(md5($Code2))
echo $Response
# gives "7a856cb4a061ec00ffdf9bca23caffa2"
# I this is the correct calculated Value!!!!!
```

Now I have to "translate" this script in shell ( to work on a synology diskstation) But the calculated results do not match, I need help.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh


Password = "D e o t 2 3 3 S w i t c h"
Challenge = "6 1 7 e 3 d 3 f"
    hash3=$(echo -n "$Challenge-$Password" |sed -e 's,.,&\n,g' | tr '\n' '\0' | md5sum | grep -o "[0-9a-z]\{32\}")
    echo "[hash32]$hash3" #[hash32]494e6cec7483a4ee0938895519a84bc7
    hash4=$(echo -n "$Challenge-$Password" | md5sum )
    echo "[hash4]$hash4" #[hash4]336d5ebc5436534e61d16e63ddfca327  -
    hash5=$(echo -n "$Challenge-$Password" | md5sum | grep -o "[0-9a-z]\{32\}")
    echo "[hash5]$hash5" #[hash5]336d5ebc5436534e61d16e63ddfca327
    hash6=$(echo -n "$Challenge-$Password" |sed -e 's,.,&\n,g'| md5sum | grep -o "[0-9a-z]\{32\}")
    echo "[hash6]$hash6" # [hash6]0a1f21a3417389e0c0a13392c79a7a89
# the "sed -e 's,.,&\n,g'" maybe the key?
```

I don't really understand the options, just know that the md5 produced dont match.

Maybe someone sees the error, thank you

Comment: It may be unrelated to your problem, but (a) assignments in POSIX-compliant shell code mustn't have spaces around the `=` and (b) `echo -n` cannot be assumed to work as intended - use `printf %s ...` instead.

Comment: thanks mklement0, if I remove the spaces , the echo variables returns blank. switch echo -n for printf %s does not change anything. left it printf

Comment: Assuming you are really executing your script with a `/bin/sh` instance: Without removing the spaces around `=`, your script will _break_; once they are removed, something like `printf %s "$Challenge-$Password"` should definitely produce output.

Comment: I execute this script on a synology disktation, no idea what instance the box is running. thank you anway

Comment: Do you have any glue on how to insert space between the letters?